# Adding column with default date gives error

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySQL, I want to add a column in database, the query I am using is

```
alter table email add column date_added date default CURRENT_DATE;
```

this above query gives an error...

i want date in format 20140905

```
select CURRENT_DATE() + 0; ## this query gives me that result
```

Comment: Have you tried `default (CURRENT_DATE());`

Comment: just tried that does not work     alter table email add column date_added date default (CURRENT_date());

Comment: It appears you can't.... http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/data-type-defaults.html but you could for a timestamp.  " With one exception, the default value must be a constant; it cannot be a function or an expression. This means, for example, that you cannot set the default for a date column to be the value of a function such as NOW() or CURRENT_DATE. The exception is that you can specify CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as the default for a TIMESTAMP column. "

Comment: alter table email add column date_added date default (CURDATE()); does not work

Comment: Just curios... can you post the error text it would be helpful for future users who experience a similar problem.

Comment: So set the default to something like '1950-01-01'. In your INSERT INTO email.... you can use curdate() for that column to always get the correct value inserted.

Comment: @user3741598 but there's like lots of places code would have to be updated.  I believe the OP was trying to avoid having to do code updates in several places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do what you're trying to do:

Per [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/data-type-defaults.html):

With one exception, the default value must be a constant; it cannot be a function or an expression. This means, for example, that **you cannot set the default for a date column to be the value of a function** such as `NOW()` or `CURRENT_DATE`. The exception is that you can specify CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as the default for a TIMESTAMP column.

Comment: alter table email add column date_added datetime default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;---this worked but not the way i want...Thanks..

Comment: The only way to accomplish what I believe you're trying to do (without modifying code all over the place) would be to set a default value of curdate() to date_added through a before insert trigger.  I would have it alter the value for the date_Added field to be curdate() if one is not provided.  This would avoid having to use a timestamp column.